# Get Token For Customer Logged With Facebook & Twitter : Magento 2

Tags: facebook, rest, api, magento2

Dears, I created a custom REST API, So customer can login Via facebook and twitter through mobile app. The API consists of one service which take some parameters and email parameter and check if this email is found or not.

-If found, then return customer id.

-If not found, then insert email and other parameters (firstname, lastname, socialid, socialtype).

**My question,** I don't save password for the customer because the response return from facebook doest not contain password, so how to get token authentication, so I can do all operations which request customer token?

I normal, I can login and get token through:

**POST**

```
 https://myhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username=test@gmail.com&password=12345
```

and response will be token.

Comment: Dunno if Twitter handles this differently, but for Facebook you will have to send the user through the login flow to be able to get a token. Just passing the user’s FB login credentials to some endpoint, and get a token back - is not possible. In fact, Facebook apps are explicitly forbidden from asking users for their FB credentials in the first place.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more in detail and give an example?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/

Comment: Please. I need an example on magento2. I mean if I want to get customers info, should i call  `https://myhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/customers/me` and Header Params: `Authorization Bearer {{facebook auth token }}`

Comment: It’s _your_ API, why are you asking me what call you need to make?

Comment: No I am asking how to call the token. I am asking to give more clear for the first comment. which login credentials do you mean in first comment?

Comment: The user’s Facebook login credentials, which they use to login to Facebook.

Comment: Ok, Do you mean to get the token through: `https://myhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/customer/token?username={{facebook email}}&password={{facebook password}}`  ? please give more clarification.

Comment: Are you talking about the Facebook user access token, or your own token? Anyway, to authenticate users with Facebook, you need to implement the Facebook login flow. Your app is not allowed to ask users for their Facebook credentials.

Comment: Why you can't give more clarification for your reply?. what you ca't understand in my question? .I mean how to get magento 2 auth token for customer logged through facebook and twitter, so he can do all other operations which requires autorization token. when user logged via facebook or twitter, I can return the responses. so what I need to generate the token in magento 2?

Comment: @Jsparo30 I have same issue about Facebook login API.  Have you got any solution?  Could you please let me know.